# Any code in python to replace the string in a row with certain word and keep the characters?

Tags: python, replace, row

I have file as shown below, * represents no matching genes while the different strings represents that those have matching genes.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX1WE.png). Now I want to replace those matching genes with the same letter like,
V1   V2  V3  V4  V5
a    a   a    *   a
b    *   b    b   b
*    *   c    c   c[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISWF0.png)
.
.
.
I have 2302 rows to change, any help is highly appreciated!! I was not allowed to post the picture - may be you could see it by clicking on "center image description here" link.

Comment: please format your question and embed the images to the post

Comment: Hi Sangii, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please follow these guidelines when you are posting a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- It will make everybody much happier :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand your question.

So, I think you want to replace each row that has a matching gene for something else? By the pictures you've added, I believe you're working with Excel/Calc, right?

Thats quite simple in python using xlrd library.
The code to read your spreadsheet and write a new file replacing each cell which value is other than '*' for something else would be something like this:

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('spreadsheet/path/')
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
with open('newfile/path/', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    for i in range(sheet.nrows):
        for j in range(sheet.ncols):
                if '*' == str(sheet.cell_value(i, j) or 'V1' == str(sheet.cell_value(i, j) or 'V2' == str(sheet.cell_value(i, j) or 'V3' == str(sheet.cell_value(i, j) or 'V4' == str(sheet.cell_value(i, j) or 'V5' == str(sheet.cell_value(i, j):
                    outfile.write(str(sheet.cell_value(i, j)))
                else:
                    outfile.write(str(sheet.cell_value(i, j)).replace('string to be replaced', 'string to replace'))
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you @Joao heron! I will try with this.